# How to disable the browser's ability to track if it's window is actively in use?

Tags: asp.net, windows, google-chrome, jsp, webbrowser-control

How does the browser come to know when we are actively clicking on it and when we have clicked out of it?
Is there a method using which we can disable the browser's ability to know when we have clicked out or switched apps?
I am using chorme on Windows right now, Mozilla will also do.
Thank you in advance!